# Problem with nesting navigators inside index in expo router

Tags: expo-router

I have the following folder structure in an expo router project:

[image]

And I am getting the following error:

```
Found screens with the same name nested inside one another. Check:
(tabs) > index, (tabs) > index > index
```

This happened because I want my default (index) view to have a stack layout, which is nested inside the tabs layout. When my `index.tsx` view was just a file instead of a `index/` folder as it is now, things were working swimmingly.

This looks like the expo-router team not considering this naming collision edge case to me, but I am not sure.

Any one have any idea of how can I nest navigators inside the default (index) view?